# CloudStorageAccount, making TableQuery request

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to make a query to my CloudTable. What I did before it was getting all elements of certain table but that takes a lot of time.

```
public static List<CollectItem> GetCollectItems(string connectionString, string tableName, DateTime dateTime)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

        // Create the table client.
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        // Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
        CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);

        TableContinuationToken token = null;
        List<CollectItem> entities = new List<CollectItem>();

        do
        {
            var queryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented(new TableQuery<CollectItem>(), token);
            entities.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
            token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
        } while (token != null);

        entities = entities.Where(x => x.Timestamp.DateTime.Year == dateTime.Year &&
                                       x.Timestamp.DateTime.Month == dateTime.Month &&
                                       x.Timestamp.DateTime.Day == dateTime.Day).ToList();

        return entities;
    }
```

Then i tried creating some query conditions

```
do
        {
            TableQuery<CollectItem> itemStockQuery = new TableQuery<CollectItem>().Where(
                                                                        TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForInt("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.Equal, dateTime)
                                                                        );

            var queryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented(itemStockQuery, token);
            entities.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
            token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
        } while (token != null);
```

But now what it does is compere Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute .... And i need to compere only Year, Month and Day.
And then i tried creating this but it said its a bad request.

```
TableQuery<CollectItem> itemStockQuery = new TableQuery<CollectItem>().Where(
                                                                        TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForInt("Timestamp.DateTime.Day", QueryComparisons.Equal, dateTime.Day)
                                                                        );
```

My question is how can i create query request on Timestamp but only compere to Year, Month and Day property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a column and make an index on it. Your currend datetime-column is not indexed and shouldn't be and that's the reason your query takes long time.

You can create a date-column without time-informationen and make an index on that column or you can specify your own format eg. 20200928 as int column for your date.

Comment: I like idea of creating column that will store date in int or string format. But I thing that its impossible to put index on that column. CloudTable have only to indexed column PartitionKey and RowKey and its impossible to add more indexed columns. If I am wrong please tell me how to do it. Also if I not put index on it and make a search would it take a significant more time to return entities?

Comment: you are right! It depends by your model design. You can create multiple tables with required specified RowKeys which returns your entities you select . https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide#optimize-queries-for-table-storage